# Is it possible to compile Swift 2 code in Xcode 7 and run it on an iOS 11.1 iPhone 6?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have an iphone 6 running ios 11.1

I have an old program that I need to run, and I tried to convert it to Swift 4 but wasn't translated properly (runtime errors mostly). Just want to run it and test it out. I do have xcode 8 and xcode 9 as well but since it's written in Swift 2.x I have to use either Xcode 8 or 7.

Running it in Xcode 7 I get

```
Could not find Developer Disk Image
```

Running it in Xcode 8 I get

```
This iPhone 6 is running iOS 11.1.1 (15B150), which may not be 
supported by this version of Xcode.
```

Is there a way to run this on a physical device or I must convert it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that. Install new Xcode version ( 9 ) and extract sdk image. Put it into your 7th folder, and you can run from Xcode 7 on iOS 11 device. But wonder, iOS 11 works only with 64x architecture, so apps should not be compiled in 32bit

Comment: While this might work, it's not a good idea. The code really should be migrated.

Comment: @rmaddy absolutely agree. Has to be migrated. This is just little workaround)))

Comment: @МаксудДаудов So I should get the SDK of Xcode 9 and place the SDK inside the Xcode 7?

Comment: @МаксудДаудов do you happen to have a link to extracting the SDK by any chance? - THank you.

Comment: @Marin, use `ln -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/11.1\ \(14E5230d\)/ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport` and replace Xcode-beta and Xcode to according your xcodes names. Remember here, we copy from Xcode-beta to Xcode

Comment: @МаксудДаудов Will try thank you :) I tried moving it by copy and paste but didn't quite work...

Comment: @Marin copy and paste folder 11.1 (Whole folder) to your Xcode DeviceSupport folder.

Comment: @Marin also check twice if your app has been built in 64-bit mode

Comment: Yes it worked thank you !  I will convert it soon enough but wanted to test it again

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can run your Xcode 7/Swift 2 app on an iOS 11 device (assuming the app is built for 64-bit) but you can't run it (debug it) through Xcode. You would need to do an archive build then export the ipa for Ad-hoc deployment and install the app via iTunes.

Don't bother with any of that. Use Xcode 8 and use its conversion tool to migrate your code to Swift 3. Get all the compiler issues resolved. Then use Xcode 9 and to build and test your app on your iOS 11 device. Optionally you can (and probably should) also migrate to Swift 4.

Swift 2 is long dead. You need to migrate. The longer you wait, the harder it will be.

Comment: I upvoted your answer and don't want to mislead others  , will convert it soon enough (I already have a swift 3 version which is not working quite well) But wanted to go back and see how the original worked.